# Does CGAL 2D Conforming Mesh support fix points?

Tags: cgal

In my meshing application I will have to specify fix points within a domain. The idea is that, the fix points must also be the element points after the domain is being meshed.

Furthermore, the elements around the fix points should be more dense. The general concept is that for the fix points, there should exist a radius `r` around those points, such that the mesh size inside `r` is of different sizes than outside of the `r`. The mesh sizes inside and outside of the `r` should be specifiable.

Are these two things doable in [CGAL 2D Mesh algorithm](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your wording, all the input point of the initial constrained Delaunay triangulation will be fix points, because the 2D mesh generator only insert new points in the triangulation: it never removes any point.

As for the density, you can copy, paste, and modify a criteria class, such as [`CGAL::Delaunay_mesh_size_criteria_2<CDT>`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/classCGAL_1_1Delaunay__mesh__size__criteria__2.html) so that the local size upper bound is smaller around the fix points.

Now, the difficulty is how to implement that new size policy. Your criteria class could store a const reference to another `Delaunay_triangulation_2`, that contains only the fixed points you want. Then, for each triangle query, you can call [`nearest_vertex`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Delaunay__triangulation__2.html) and then actually check if the distance between the query point is smaller that the radius bound of your circles. For a triangle, you can either verify that for only its barycenter, or for all three points of the triangle. Then, according to the result of that/those query(s), you can modify the size bound, in the code of your copy of [`CGAL::Delaunay_mesh_size_criteria_2<CDT>`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/classCGAL_1_1Delaunay__mesh__size__criteria__2.html).

Comment: I've updated my question to make the definition of "around" more precise. Do let me know whether it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, no points will be removed from the triangulation by the mesher.
Note however that if you insert points too close to a constraint this will induce a refinement of the constraint while it is not Gabriel.

Comment: can you explained what is the non-Gabriel constraint requirement?

Comment: the circumscribing circle of any constrained edge does not contain any point.